# SSRS Rectangle visibility based on Parameter Value

Tags: reporting, visual-studio, ssrs-2008-r2, microsoft-dynamics

I am creating a `Report` in `SSRS`.
Its a `Dynamic 2011 CRM` Report.
I have created some `Tables`.
And some `Rectangles`.
Each `Rectangle` contains some `Tables`.
Also there is a `Parameter` that contains value from 1 to 4.
It is a `multiple values` parameter. 
The goal is that the user select parameters( one or more ) and then tables based on the rec visibility condition appear.( Maybe two rec appear, or maybe all of them)
We all know that there is `IN operator` in SQL Syntax.
But I do not know how to make it here.
I googled a lot but no success.
Here is what I tried in rec visibility.

```
=Parameters!type.Value.Equals("1")
```

And in the second table :

```
    =Parameters!type.Value.Equals("2")
```

till the last rectangle.

Even changed to :

```
=Parameters!type.IsMultiValue.Equals("1")
```

I Also Put both of them in `=iif`, but no success.
How can I perform this?
Visibility of rectangle based on the multiple values parameter.
Any help will appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28244115/show-hide-columns-in-ssrs-report-2012-based-on-multiselect-parameter). Basically, you want to combine all the values in your selected list using Join then use InStr to detect if the value in question is there.

So if you have Rectangle Rec1 which relies on param option "Rec1Visible" in parameter RecVisibility being selected, then an expression like this should work (pseudo names) for Rec1's visibility property:

```
=IIF(InStr(JOIN(Parameters!RecVisibility.Value,","),"Rec1Visible")>0,true,false)
```

Use the same code for each visibility expression, with the relevant value, to control the visibility of your rectangles.

Comment: So I must try this in each Rec visibility.
I will let you know.

Comment: I tried this for first option  : =IIF(InStr(JOIN(Parameters!type.Value,","),"1")=0,true,false)
This for next rec :
=IIF(InStr(JOIN(Parameters!type.Value,","),"2")=0,true,false)
Now what ever I select( Parameter option) I appear rectangle based on the visibility condition.
And It works !
Thanks.

Comment: Awesome. Feel free to upvote the answer if it was helpful.